# swift custom UITableViewCell with TextView inside disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to get a custom tableView cell with a textView inside working in my tableView.  I have made a custom UITableViewCell with a textView inside it.

I can get the custom made UITableViewCell with the textView inside to appear in the UITableView.

I can click inside the textView to type something, but when I finish typing and click on another tableViewCell, the first tableViewCell with the textView inside disappears.  After disappearing, it becomes an empty tableViewCell.  XCode gives this message: 
"no index path for table cell being reused"

However, when I scroll away in the tableView and scroll back to the empty tableViewCell, it reappears.
I don't know how to keep the tableViewCell from disappearing.  It seems like the answer has something to do with using the restorationIdentifier inside of UITableView, but I'm not sure how to use it.  In the docs, it says to use restorationIdentifier for state preservation.

Here is the relevant code I have:

```
inside ViewDidLoad():
tableView.registerClass(PhotoAndRateTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: ReuseIds.reviewCell)
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "PhotoAndRateTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: ReuseIds.reviewCell)
```

inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var section = indexPath.section

    let cell = UITableViewCell()
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ReuseIds.reviewCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as PhotoAndRateTableViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Where are you creating your text view?

Comment: the textView is created in the xib file for the custom tableViewCell.  The file is PhotoAndRateTableViewCell.xib  This way I can use autoLayout on it.

Comment: I can get the tableViewCell to reappear now using:  func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }.  However, the data inside doesn't seem to get preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing the dequeue procedure:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ReuseIds.reviewCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PhotoAndRateTableViewCell

if (cell == nil) {
   cell = PhotoAndRateTableviewCell();
}
```

You want to reuse a cell if available, or create a new one if not. In your case, you're creating a cell every time (of the generic class) and then attempting to dequeue a cell from your custom class (which has never been created)

As far as preserving the data, you need to implement the prepareForReuse method in the table cell which should clear whatever index specific data was contained in the cell. Then in cellForRow you can re-set the data for the cell for re-appearance

Comment: I tried typing this in, but for (cell == nil), XCode has an error, saying "Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(UITableViewCell, NilLiterl ...

Comment: I got the check for (cell == nil) working, but the same problem still occurs.  From the documentation, it looks like I need to implement the UIDataSourceModelAssociation protocol.  However, there don't seem to be examples of doing this within a tableView